# Name of young adult book about girl with metal hair, maybe silver, that young boy uses to make a radio. She may be from outer space

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

This is a book I read sometime between 1960 and 1970.  A young boy meets a girl and become friends.  I think he learns that she is from another planet or outer space.  They are working on some kind of radio and he needs wire.  Her hair is wire and she cuts off some of it for him to use.  Maybe silver or platinum?  Is was a hardcover about 6" by 8" approximately.  It was for young adults or kids.

Comment: If you think that an answer is correct, please click the check mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 13):

This was [*Martin and His Friend from Outer Space*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/36288245-martin-and-his-friend-from-outer-space) (1955) by Ivo Duka and Helen Kolda. Martin lives in Manhattan. Martin's friend, Aknele-Alpha, hears his radio message and comes to visit from her home on one of Saturn's moons. She has dark hair with a gold streak that is made of real gold. If I remember the story right, she clips off some of her gold hair so Martin can call her ride back. But she gets kidnapped for her hair first. It's quite a story.

Ivo Duka is a pseudonym for [Ivo Duchacek](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?826191).

The novel was remarkable in being illustrated with black-and-white photographs, the work of Helen Kolda. When I read the book at the age of 9 or so, I was perplexed by this "proof" that all these events really occurred. I worked out that it was fiction, but never forgot the book.

Comment: Why do these aliens always have Greek names...?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with stars being designated by Greek letters: Alpha Centauri, Beta Tauri, Delta Pavonis, etc.